# Recursive pattern rules in GNU Make

Tags: gnu-make

I have a pattern rule which builds several artifacts, some of which depend on each other. GNU Make doesn't seem to be able to cope with this case.

Here is a minimal example:

```
$ cat Makefile 
.SECONDEXPANSION:

foo_DEPS := bar-thing

%-thing: $$($$*_DEPS)
    touch $@
$ make foo-thing
make: *** No rule to make target 'foo-thing'. Stop.
```

If the dependency of `foo-thing` *either* exists already *or* has an explicit (non-pattern) rule then it works.

Is there a trick to getting this to work? Or another way of achieving the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me, I don't like pattern rules.
They make the build a bit woolly.
It's never really clear which ones *make* will choose in any given circumstance.
Consequently I always cancel the built-in rules with `-Rr` (also gives a useful speed up, and makes the output of `make -d` a *lot* saner).

The patterns themselves are useful however.
You can explicitly apply patterns to pre-existing sources via *static pattern rules*.
These are much nicer IMHO.

They look like this:

*list-of-sources* `:` *target-patterns* `:` *dependency-patterns*

So just like an ordinary pattern rule, except that the sources that the rule applies to are explicitly listed.
In your case we end up with

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:

foo_DEPS := bar-thing

foo-thing: %-thing: $${$$*_DEPS}
     touch $@
```

which I think will work nicely, even when *foo-thing* does not exist.